# Помогите разобраться: причастный оборот либо цельное выражение?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

«Все сделавшие donation на любую сумму будут считаться создателями фильма...» Я бы обособила - сделавшие donation на любую сумму - . Здесь ведь нет цельного выражения итд - все сделавшие...

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, запятые не нужны. Розенталь: "Определительные, указательные и притяжательные местоимения не отделяются запятой от следующего за ними причастного оборота, тесно примыкая к нему, например: *Все опубликованные в книге фактические данные были автором проверены*" ([§92. Обособленные согласованные и несогласованные определения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm))

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Да и позже не все пишущие стихи переходят на прозу или бухгалтерские отчёты… [Юлия Рахаева. «Стакан есть, дорогой читатель?». Книжный развал (2002)]

В результате все находившиеся на сцене сталкивались лбами, поскольку не знали, где же она, эта правильная дорога, в какую сторону надо "двигаться" архитектуре. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]

И если раньше всех возвращающихся с работы тщательно обыскивали, то теперь обыскивали кое-как... [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]

И ― туда же на вторые десять лет все отсидевшие только по разу. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к сказанному есть два замечания.

(1) Некорректно говорить, что **все** сделали пожертвование **на любую сумму**.
(2) Я бы обошелся словами русского языка.

Фразу следовало бы перестроить, например так:

**Все сделавшие пожертвования будут считаться создателями фильма(,) независимо от пожертвованной суммы.**

Запятая опциональна.